# Window not resizing on gnome shell

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-shell, window

I am using archlinux with gnome shell 3.14.3-2 and I am unable to resize windows using eather `alt+f8` or `alt+space -> resize`.

Pressing `alt+f8` and the moving the mouse moves the window, while it is suppose to (and used to) resize it. Same goes for `alt+space -> resize`.

Has anyone even experienced the same issue ? Is there a known fix ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this behavior. Most likely a bug... You can always use the arrows to resize. Another way: while holding `Super/Win` key down, click&drag with the middle mouse button/scroll wheel.

Comment: I made most of this irrelevant by using a tilling window manager extention (shellshape) but still it's good to be able to resize floating windows from time to time. Thank you for the Super+middle button tricks, the bad thing is it can't be used on touchpads

Comment: It can be used on touchpads too. Open a terminal and run: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences resize-with-right-button true`(this swaps middle-click and right-click when used with Super). You can then resize with Super + touchpad right-click + touch&drag.

Comment: same on Debian Bullseye and someone repported from [xfce](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9281). I can only `alt+f8` then `left` or `right` not `up` or `down`

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot resize with the "Super" or Windows key down and using the middle "scroll wheel" button on the mouse...
Try using "ALT" and the middle button. I could only resize on the top right corner, but I still was able to get it done.
It seems that the gtk interface is not wholly baked. The rounded edges also have the black corner, showing that it is a symbolic rounded edge and not drawn by the display engine.